# How to reduce sensitivity in Jetpack Compose Pager in newer Compose versions?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

To customize `Pager` swipe behavior there is `flingBehavior: SnapFlingBehavior` parameter in `Pager` composable function which can be instantiated using `PagerDefaults.flingBehavior(...)`. On newer Compose versions overload of this function which takes `snapVelocityThreshold` is deprecated. How to change `Pager` sensitivity using new API without `snapVelocityThreshold`?

Answer (score 1):

The `SnapFlingBehavior` in general now uses another way to determine when to switch from the fling animation (`lowVelocityAnimationSpec` or `highVelocityAnimationSpec`) to the snapping animation (`snapAnimationSpec`). It is done implicitly now by the values returned from the used `SnapLayoutInfoProvider`, there is no explicit cutoff value anymore like the `snapVelocityThreshold` that you would like to use.

For the `PagerDefaults.flingBehavior()` that `SnapLayoutInfoProvider` is an implementation detail which cannot be directly influenced and there is no way to specify when the snapping animation should start. There is a comment in the implementation of the PagerDefaults that describes the behaviour that was chosen by the developers:

```
// We'd like the approach animation to finish right before the last page so we can
// use a snapping animation for the rest.
```

*Approach animation* is the fling animation, *last page* means the page before the target page where the entire snap/fling animation should settle.

If this is not sufficient for you you can always create your own `SnapFlingBehavior` and pass that to the Pager. This will be quite complex if you try not to fall behind the other features and the support for edge cases that the default fling behavior of the pager provides.

If you *do* decide to create your own `SnapFlingBehavior` you could use `rememberSnapFlingBehavior` as a starting point, though it uses slighty different animation specs under the hood than the pager defaults do. If you want to have control over the animation specs, just use the constructor of `SnapFlingBehavior` to create an instance. The first parameter is the `SnapLayoutInfoProvider` that you want to customize. Although you only need to implement two methods for this interface, these will be quite complex. I would recommend you take a look at the implementation of `PagerDefaults.flingBehavior()` to get an idea of what this could look like.

Comment: Do you suggest to use 
`fun rememberSnapFlingBehavior(snapLayoutInfoProvider: SnapLayoutInfoProvider): SnapFlingBehavior`
for custom `SnapFlingBehavior` which can be controller by custom `SnapLayoutInfoProvider`?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend creating your own `SnapFlingBehavior` for this from scratch. If you insist, though, I edited my post so you can get an idea where to start.